# Drawing a circle with focus on quadrant and different angle-starting point

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So, I'm trying to draw a graph, and I have the following MWE as a starting point:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,>=stealth]

\draw[->,red] (3mm,0mm) arc (0:135:3mm) node[midway,xshift=2mm,yshift=2mm] {$\theta$};
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw[fill=green,pattern=dots,pattern color=black!60!green]  
node[below,xshift=2mm]{O} (0,0)  -- node[above,black!60!green]{$r$} (135:1cm) node[left,xshift=2mm,yshift=2mm]{$\textbf{P}(x,y)$} -- node[left,black!60!green]{$y$} +(0,-0.707)  -- node[below,black!60!green]{$x$} (0,0) -- cycle;

\draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[anchor=east]{$y$};
\draw (-.607,0) -- +(0,.1) -- +(-.1,0.1);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Which outputs the following image:

[image]

I would like to modify it, in order to:

1. Delete P(x,y) point, and the inner triangle.
2. Converting the triangle in a square, to highlight for instance the second quadrant, maintaing the dotted green pattern. Here a reference for the quadrant numbering:

[image]

3. I would like that the angle arc ("theta" in the image) to start from the Y-axis, instead of X-asis, always with an anti-clockwise direction.
4. Substitute "theta" with "psi".

**UPDATE**

To give you an idea:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to draw a rectangle with segment OP as a diagonal? It's not clear enough to me.

Comment: Yes, the segment OP can be maintained, without the P(x,y) reference. Moreover, if the segment OP could be drawn with less opacity and dashed, it would be better. @SebGlav I will upload an example though, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Following OP's drawing, I edit my answer to provide something more likely to fulfill his needs.

[image: 2nd try]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,>=stealth]
        \path[fill=green,pattern=dots,pattern color=black!60!green] (0,0) rectangle (-1.45,1.45);
        \draw[->,red] (0mm,3mm) arc (90:135:3mm) node[circle,inner sep=0pt,fill=white,midway,above=2pt] {$\psi$};
        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
        
        \draw[dashed,opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (135:1cm);
        \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And with the sector travelled by the angle filled:

[image: 3rd try]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,>=stealth]
        \path[fill=green,pattern=dots,pattern color=black!60!green] (0,0) rectangle (-1.45,1.45);
        \draw[->,red] (0mm,3mm) arc (90:135:3mm) node[circle,inner sep=0pt,fill=white,midway,above=2pt] {$\psi$};
        
        \fill[red,opacity=0.3] (0,0) -- (0,1cm) arc(90:135:1cm) -- cycle; <-- This is what was added

        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
        
        \draw[dashed,opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (135:1cm);
        \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @SebGlav, just one more question before confirming your answer as accepted: Eventually, how could I fill only the "slice" traveled by the angle, keeping dots just inside the circle?

Comment: You just have to fill the sector, I'll edit my answer once more.